# Setting the value of a undefined object

Tags: javascript

I would like to set a value to an object which is into a deep structure.

Let's say the value of `myObject.language.settings.color` should be `red`.

Out of my field of vision. Setting this value is based on the following way:

```js
const myObject = {};
myObject.language = {};
myObject.language.settings = {};
myObject.language.settings.color = 'red';
```

That is a long process if the objects before do not exist yet.

I am looking for a shorter way to handle this. E.g. using `myObject.language.settings.color = 'red';` but that would return an error, that says *myObject is not defined*.

Is there a simpler solution than that?

Comment: const myObject = {language:{settings:{color:'red'}}};

Comment: @TimMickey Great solution! Thanks!